# Android EditText type number fazer aparecer teclado com números e virgula

Tags: android, edittext, number-format, valor-monetário

Estou trabalhando com valores no editText e preciso que o input seja somente com números e virgula para ponto flutuante. Eu tentei com inputType="numberDecimal" mas ao abrir o teclado só permite o ponto e não a virgula. preciso o input no padrão brasileiro... ex: 1,00

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/tf"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:digits="0123456789,"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
 />
```

Alguem ja passou por isso?

Comment: Você teria como apresentar o código em questão aqui @programadorCS ?

Comment: opa, desculpa, havia colocado mas por algum motivo não apareceu na pergunta, coloquei na resposta

Comment: Edit sua pergunta e adicione o código por favor.

Comment: Aqui tem uma solução https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydF4sQr8kAs

Comment: Murillo Comino, não funcionou

Comment: O que eu costumo fazer é deixar o input com o "." mesmo, mas altero o textwatcher que pra quando usar o "." troque para ",".

Comment: Murillo Comino  estou dando replace no onTextChanged porem esta travando o componente parece que entra em loop quando digito

Answer (score 0):

consegui criando um textWatcher para o componente:

```
 TextWatcher() {
        private String current = "";
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {
                String clean = s.toString();
                if(current.contains(",") && clean.contains(".") ){
                    clean = clean.replace(".", "");
                }
                clean = clean.replace(".", ",");
                current = clean;
                editText.setText(current);
                editText.setSelection(current.length());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
```

A questão é que agora alguns dispositivos no teclado o botão ','(virgula) se transforma em '.' (ponto), preciso que seja o teclado com virgula apenas.

Answer (score 0):

consegui pessoal, houve uma confusão de teclado de diferentes diapositivos, bug do android.
ao invés de fazer um novo teclado chamei o padrão 12 digitos para ser sempre o mesmo, e limitei digitos e virgula no xml do EditText

xml:

```
android:digits="0123456789,"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

java:

```
editText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
```